# Finding all possible options in a multi-select "type" searchbar .(webscrapping)

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrap (in Python, using the bs4 library) the data on this website : [the content is in french :)](https://www.cessionpme.com/annonces,fonds-de-commerce-entreprise-tabac-presse-loto,45,1,offres.html)  .

More precisely the search bar called 'TYPE DE BIENS' is kind of 'multi-select' (sorry if I don't use the correct terms I am a complete beginner) type of search-bar meaning if I type the letter 'a' (for instance) I get many options possible [see the picture for more infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2K17.png). My goal is to get all the possible values of this multiselect search bar (for instance in the picture, I would like to get the strings 'Agence Immobilière','Agriculture - Viticulture' , and so on ... ).

I tried to type all letters and write by hand all the outputs for instance I typed 'a' then I got all the fields then I typed 'b' and did the same , ... but this approach is long and I found that I missed some items : for instance if you type 'Tabac' in the bar you will get 'Tabac - Presse - Loto' in the results but i don't get this field when I just type 'T' or 't' !

Is there a way to easily find all the fields possible ?
Thank you for your time !

I tried to inspect the html element of the search bar (developper tool ) but didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Refer the below working code with explanation:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.cessionpme.com/annonces,fonds-de-commerce-entreprise-tabac-presse-loto,45,1,offres.html")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# Click on Accept cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Accepter et fermer']"))).click()
# Below 2 lines will clear the field and enter text "a"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "secteur_activite_fdc"))).clear()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "secteur_activite_fdc"))).send_keys("a")
# Below line will store all suggestions into a variable 
auto_suggestion_values = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "livesearch_rubrique_fdc")))
# Iterate the varaibale list and print each item
for value in auto_suggestion_values:
    print(value.text)
```

**Console output:**

```
Agence Immobilière
Agriculture - Viticulture
Agroalimentaire
Alimentation
Animalerie - Chasse - Pêche
Autres Production et Bâtiment
Bar - Brasserie - Tabac
Beauté - Esthétique - Coiffure
Boucherie - Charcuterie
Boulangerie - Pâtisserie
Cadeaux - Fleurs
Camping
Carrelage - Maçonnerie
Chambres d'hôtes - Gîtes
Charpente - Menuiserie

Process finished with exit code 0
```